# Android studio tools to build client for REST API

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, scaffolding, rest

in .NET platform nobody build manually client of REST functions, need to set endpoint URL and embedded in Visual Studio tool review endpoint URL with ?WSDL suffix (for REST in SOAP/WSDL/DISCO format) or /help (with WebApi format), than tools make automatically code with all methods to communication with all parameters. I'm newbie in Java and Kotlin programming - how to perform similar function in Android Studio? Need something plugin or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is something like that in android Studio, you should implement this functionality manually, but there is a library called Retrofit that makes it so easy to do it, I reccomend you check it out..